# How to configure internet access in Virtual Device

Tags: settings, android-emulator

My development machine is behind a proxy and Eclipse can access internet with no problem (the SDK Manager is downloading / installing packages and my proxy is configured in Eclipse).

When I start a VD, I can't see any network option in Settings | Networking (only the Bluetooth one) and I can't access internet with browser (connection problem).

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

**To setup Proxy address on AVD:**

1. Go to Settings>WIRELESS & NETWORKS>Mobile networks>Mobile networks settings>Access Point Names
2. add access point by clicking "+" button and then type favorite name for Name, favorite name for APN, fixed Proxy and port. If necessary put user name and password.

[image: Edit access point]

**To setup DNS address on AVD:**

1. Run below command.

   emulator -avd <MACHINE_NAME> -dns-server <DNS_IP_ADDRESS>

**FYI:**

https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#dns

Comment: I think I have a DNS problem. Without your tip I can access local hosts (local web server) using IP address bu not adress name. With your tip I can't access anything ( proxy auth error)

Comment: I need to understand how AVD works. If it needs a IP address or static configuration, no way to this work in my job because the Admin does not allow to assign IP addresses for my own. I think all network traffic was through Eclipse and its configuration or using NAT.

Comment: I can say It's proxy setting issue on AVD not IP address, we have to setup proxy on each AVD once if it needs to access internet from AVD. you can get more information about emulator from   http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: Yeap. Agree. But I can't set the proxy as you tell, because I have no DNS and the proxy IP changes every time the Administrator wants. I can access any site via IP, but not via address. Where to set the DNS in AVD?

Comment: @Magno C, How about this link? http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#dns If it could resolve the name of host by DNS, you are not worried about proxy ip address changes.

Comment: The link you give me (http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#dns) helps to solve my problem. The solution was to start the emulator by using command line and passing the DNS : `emulator -avd <MACHINE_NAME> -dns-server <DNS_IP_ADDRESS>`. Thanks. BTW, AND configure proxy as you said, inside Android.

Comment: Just for check : I also created a HTTP_PROXY global enviroment variable in Windows with `<user>:<password>@<ADDRESS>:<PORT>`. Any changes needs to reboot the machine (or kill the adb service task)

Comment: I see my question have more than 1000 views. If this answer helps you, do not forget to upvote! Thanks.

Comment: What is DNS_IP_ADDRESS here?

Comment: @Igor G: It's your DNS IP address. You can see it by using `ipconfig /all` in windows or `ifconfig` in linux.